# pip install dronekit --upgrade does not work

Tags: dronekit-python

I am trying to upgrade my Dronekit 2.0.0rc.4

As of 10 minutes ago, they are up to 2.0.0cr.10

I need this version because apparently the older versions don't have a way to adjust baud rate when using 3DR radios.

I try

`pip install dronekit --upgrade`

but get message that I am already up-to-date.

Please advise.

Windows 8.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install dronekit -UI`. It ignores installed versions and any "apparent" requirements are in your environment. I also recommend `pip uninstall dronekit; pip install dronekit` as the easiest mechanism to avoid pip woes.

Comment: Okay, I did the `pip uninstall dronekit` but then did `pip install --pre dronkit` and that worked. `pip install dronekit` gives errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip install --pre dronekit
```